# Как в переменую записать имя файла с датой?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Есть файл, в нём есть такой код:

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
FILE='backup_$DATE.tar.gz'
```

Как в переменную FILE правильно записать имя с датой, к примеру `backup_2019-01-17.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хватает скобок:

```
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Теперь все работает:

```
FILE="backup_$DATE.tar.gz" // -> backup_2019-01-17.tar.gz
```

Comment: двойные кавычки, а не одинарные.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да.